# How to put material select and label in the same row side by side

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I want to be seem that language label and select options in same row.But I couldn't make them in same row using bootstrap col-md-6.Whole form is seperated into same col-sm-6 columns inside row.
As you can see on the image language label and select doesnt look like on the same row, very far from each other and select field got shrinked.How to make them look well and normal on the same row?

[image]

Here's what I tried below:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:10px;">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h4>Language:</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:left">
                      <mat-form-field>
                          <select matNativeControl required>
                            <option value="english">English</option>
                            <option value="german">German</option>
                          </select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            ...other form elements
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following with your `h4` tag

```
    <h4 style="display:inline">Language:</h4>
```

Demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzfrnt)

Comment: Oh god.I didn't expect this would be that easy.Thanks very much